# Site templates missing in SharePoint 2016 on -prem

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, site-template, sub-site

I'm using SharePoint 2016 on premises , I was working on installing some site features, while doing so suddenly this happen,

while creating new sub site, I don't have option to select the template.
[image] 
Also, the option to create a new sub-site is also missing.
[image: e]
How to fix these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate the **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** in the site collection level.

Then go to this page "**YourSiteURL/_layouts/15/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx**” this will take you to the site template configuration page. There you can select and configure what are the site templates should be available in the subsite creation.

For details refer to the below article:

[SharePoint – On-Premise – O365: Site template is missing from a SharePoint subsite.](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/when-certain-site-creation-template-is-missing-from-a-subsite-how-to-fix-this/)

Comment: thank you so much for giving this solution, it worked and saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: @JeganBaskaran - Glad to know it helped you and worked. :-)